# Change dropdown window border and scrollbar in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a dropdown button in flutter and I have successfully colored the background of the list. I however cannot figure out how to customize the border of the dropdown list nor how to customize the scrollbar in the dropdown list. Please note that I am not talking about the border of the button itself, but the square that pops up with a dropdown list, as shown on the image below.

[image: Dropdown]

As seen on the image, the dropdown window is squared. I want to customize it to be more round. I also want to change the scrollbar color but cannot figure out where to do it. I have changed scrollbar color on other elements such as lisviews.

My dropdown is below. It is nested in a `Theme` to change the background color of the window.

```
return Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      canvasColor: secondaryColor,
    ),
    child: DropdownButton<String>(
      value: currentColor,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward, color: primaryColor),
      style: TextStyle(
          color: primaryColor
      ),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: primaryColor,
      ),
      onChanged: onChanged,
      items: menuItems
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: text(value, 0.0),
        );
      }).toList(),
    )
);
```

Comment: I'm sorry to inform your that there is not pre-built way to do DropdownMenus with rounded corners. Any modification you do to the widget will only affect the button, and not the menu that shows for the user to select the item. I also haven't found any packages that provide this. You would have to build your own.

Comment: Probably extending the existing one and modifying it for your purposes might be the best approach.

Comment: There is this package [menu_button](https://pub.dev/packages/menu_button) that allows some customisation. You could give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

[DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) widget is limited on what you can access easily. If you're lazy to extend the class and override its properties, you can consider using [dropdown_button2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2) plugin. To modify the dropdown buttons, you can change its properties using `DropdownButton2.buttonDecoration()`

```dart
DropdownButton2(
  buttonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.black26,
    ),
    color: Colors.redAccent,
  ),
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved rounded border for dropdownButton by simply using the borderRadius property.

For your purpose it would look like this:

```
return Theme(
data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
  canvasColor: secondaryColor,
),
child: DropdownButton<String>(
  value: currentColor,
  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward, color: primaryColor),
  style: TextStyle(
      color: primaryColor
  ),
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(8)
  underline: Container(
    height: 2,
    color: primaryColor,
  ),
  onChanged: onChanged,
  items: menuItems
      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: text(value, 0.0),
    );
  }).toList(),
));
```

As far as I know there is no possibility to manipulate the shape of the dropdownButton-Scrollbar.